Mixing emission with transparency is not transparent
Couldn't find in similar posts the exact scenario I am facing.
I am trying to create a material in Eevee that would look like a hypnosis wave (It would be a circle that is getting larger by inserting key frames in the Compare shader's values).
Here are my shaders:

As you can see I am implementing this by mixing the emission and transparent material.
The issue is, though I am mixing the two materials the output is not completely transparent. It is somewhat dark (compared to what is not behind the material.)
How can I make this material completely transparent except for the white circle that is the emission?

Short version : 50% of the shader is an Emission one, which doesn't have transparency. So it is expected to not get any full transparency. You should plug the 3 left-most nodes to the Factor of the Mix Shader instead.
